# What topology has $Pic(X)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $Pic(X):=\{\mbox{Holomorphic line bundles on } X\}/\sim$ be the group of isomorphism classes of line bundles on $X$. It is well-know and easy to prove that, working in Cech cohomology, $Pic(X) \simeq H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X^*)$. Is there a good method in order to give a topology on $Pic(X)$? Is it possible to do this using the exact sequence in cohomology $$ \cdots \to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X, \mathcal{O}) \to \cdots \,\,\, ?$$ Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does a topology on $\text{Pic}(X)$ do for you? Why do you want it?

Comment: In the case that $X$ is a Riemann surface, I think what you're after is called the Jacobi variety.

Comment: I don't know... but I'd like to know if there is a way to induce a topology on $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X^*)$ starting, for examples from $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$...

Comment: $H^2 (X, \mathbb{Z})$ is a finitely generated abelian group if $X$ is compact. Usually the only reasonable topology on such things is discrete...

Comment: What is the problem if $X^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is not finitely generated? Are you talling me that if $X$ is compact than I can equipe $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ with the discrete topology and after put on $Pic(X)$ the inverse-image topology?

Comment: The nature of the abelian group $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ is irrelevant for this question: see my answer.

Comment: @Mike: the construction of an algebraic variety structure on $Pic(X)$ (which is more than  merely giving it a topology, of course) for an algebraic $X$ was one of the main problems of twentieth century algebraic geometry. The  construction and   study in various degrees of generality of such a  structure  involved Weil, Chow, Chevalley, Matsusaka, Igusa,  Grothendieck, Murre and many others.

Answer (score 4):

For a  compact Kähler manifold $X$  the exact sequence $$0 \to H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}) \to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*) \stackrel {c_1}{\to} H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$$ allows you to endow $Pic^0(X)$, the group of isomorphism classes of line bundles  of first Chern class  $c_1=0$ ,  with the structure of a compact complex torus .
Indeed $ H^1(X,\mathbb Z)\subset  H^1(X, \mathcal O)$ is a lattice by Hodge theory and the quotient $H^1(X, \mathcal O)/H^1(X,\mathbb Z)$ is thus a compact (in general non-algebraic) torus of dimension $$g=\operatorname {dim}_\mathbb C H^1(X, \mathcal O)={dim}_\mathbb C H^{01}=h^{01}=b_1/2$$  (half the first Betti number of $X$).

In the case when $X$ is algebraic, the  construction of an algebraic variety structure on $Pic(X)$ is much more complicated, as I mentioned in a comment to the question.
Kleiman's  fantastic survey on the Picard scheme, whose history begins in the 17th century with James Bernoulli's study of a lemniscate linked to the bending of rods, can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504020).

Comment: Dear Georges, let me make a tiny elucidation on the subject of your last paragraph(for the benefit of other readers): $Pic^0(X)$ always  has a structure of an algebraic variety, but (say for $X$ projective) the whole group $Pic(X)$ _never_ does, since it has infinitely many connected components. Now that I mention it, I wonder if there are complete nonprojective varieties for which $Pic$ has finitely many connected components...

Comment: Dear @Asal, thanks for your comment. Actually I hadn't thought of this: since any disjoint union of schemes (or complex manifolds) is a scheme (or a complex manifold) , I sometimes forget that a variety is supposed to be of finite type over the base field and thus can have only finitely many connected components.